# Dynamic list that requires parsing, and then aggregation

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

I really would appreciate some extra eyes on this, I’m thoroughly stumped. Let me know if you have any questions or clarifications.

I have a daily reconciliation with 4 unfortunately un linked data sources. Thus far I have created a macro that can handle 3/4 sources but I've hit a wall on the 4th.

There is a sheet called "Data" with two columns that are causing issue, for discussions sake "A" & "B". A has a tag (RS##### format) and the adjacent cell B has a string of contiguous numerical text values (5-6 Digits) which are separated by commas (1234,54321,51423).

I need to parse the data in each cell of column B (row length varies from day to day).

With the Original 1st value remaining in column B and each subsequent 4-5 digit number in their own cell to the right of the original value in column Beta (which I can do successfully through VBA logic akin to text to columns, although I'm not sure its the most efficient way).

Then for each of the cells in a row, I need to re aggregate the original value and the subsequent values to the right into one contiguous list an another sheet.

EX.

The whole process would:

Step 1 (no issue - info purposes only)
‘Original Data

‘Sheet “Data”
 ‘ Columns A & B*

```
  A3            B3
```

RS1234   |  “12345, 54321, 51423”

BR4353   | “ 34567,23145,2345,6789,22222,34543”

Etc.*         | Etc.    (Until last Row)*

- Last row A & B always the same

Step 2 (have achieved using text to columns but interested in different approaches if anyone has a better idea) - mostly info purposes only)

```
Result of parsing:
```

‘Sheet “Data”
‘Columns A | B & Last column with data

A3   |   B3   |   C3  | D3     |     E3

RS1234 | 12345  | 54321 | 51423  |  55443

BR4353 |  34567 | 23145 | etc..

Etc..

- Note: if there is some way to skip this step that makes it easier I’m open to it, this was just my thinking as to where there might be a way forward.

Step 3
Result of re-aggregation:

‘Sheet “Multi”

Next available cell in Row Y|    Next available cell in row Z

```
RS1234      |       12345

RS1234      |       54321

RS1234      |       51423

BR3453      |       34567

BR4353      |       23415

etc*            |       etc. (until last row “A:B”with value on sheet “Data”)
```

Step 4: I can pick back up the process from this point.

Admittedly, I’m really stuck. I’m not a coder by trade, more of a puzzler who’s looking for answers to a problem that I can’t put down. It would save me ages and I feel like its feasible and It’s driving me nuts.

Thanks,
CrashCoding

Im stuck - I've tried to dig into loops because that's where I think this could be simplified but Im struggling to wrap my head around it.